# How can I build an RPM package with dependencies?

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools

I would like to create an RPM package from a python project on CentOS with setuptools. But I'm not able to include some dependencies via a spec in a correct way.

I would like to Install OS dependencies (and integrate in RPM)

```
 - gcc
 - python-devel
 - python-setuptools
```

and Install Python dependencies (and integrate in RPM)

```
 - psutil
 - rsa
 - pyaes
 - pyyaml
```

So anyone have an idea or some hints for the right way to include this dependencies?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your spec file you just need to say your rpm needs other packages to be installed:

```
Requires: gcc, python-devel, python-setuptools
```

same for the python dependencies:

```
Requires: python-psutil, python-rsa, python-pyaes, python-PyYAML
```

Note that you need to know the exact rpm names (for example on opensuse I found rpm **python-PyYAML** but didn't find any rpm yet containing python pyaes)

For further reading: http://rpm5.org/docs/rpm-guide.html#id3037649

Comment: Thanks for your hints, this would help me too build the final RPM-Packages.

In addition: Do you have another tipp how I can create DEBs from RPM?

Comment: There is no magic tool for that. In my company we used https://bitbucket.org/guidod/spec2deb for a while; but the result was never very satisfactory. It does the trick though...

Comment: Hey. So there is no way to install dependencies via pip in a "local folder" and then use them from there? This way they could be packaged with the RPM for distribution... I essentially have similar issue - need to have few python dependencies either packed within RPM or as requirements of, but there are no RPMs available for what I need...